# Parsing Web URL in iPhone Development

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am trying to parse a HTML string in a iPhone app.

Example:
The URL is http://www.apple.com/developer

I want to delete the "developer" part so all I have will be http://www.apple.com

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also bring it in to an `NSURL` and get the parts you want:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/developer"];
[url host]; // @"www.apple.com"
[url scheme]; // @"http"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the third slash in the string and then substring it to get the part you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `NSUrl` method `URLByDeletingLastPathComponent` or the method `pathComponents`?

```
URLByDeletingLastPathComponent
```

Returns a new URL made by deleting the last path component from the original URL.

```
pathComponents
```

Returns the individual path components of a file URL in an array.

[Here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/how-to-parse-an-nsurl-object.html) is a good tutorial/example on `NSURL` methods.